# A question about ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, anova

Question:
[image]

My problem:

Regarding the above question, a solution set was provided(although it was not explained by anyone).

There the problem was solved by "One way ANOVA" model, Yij=u+eij, where Yij is defined as the jth observation in the ith sample number..

My problem is that, here, are we considering "4 different Cylinders" as the only "source of variation" ?

If so, then what about the "different concentrations of coal" ? If they ate considered, the problem will have 2 sources of variations following a 2-way ANOVA model and not 1 way.

Please help me to point out where I am going wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four cylinders within each coal concentration are simply replicates* made under (at least notionally) identical conditions. There are two sources of variation in the model being considered -- that due to coal concentration and that due to random variation.

* When concrete is being poured (say at a building site), it is tested for strength. Some of the concrete being poured at the site is poured into multiple standard cylindrical moulds (four would be a pretty typical number), producing concrete cylinders. Once cured and capped, they are subject to increasing compression (by a kind of hydraulic press) in the vertical direction until a fracture appears.